# [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Scheduler.Models.PatientModel.Patient'.]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm getting an HttpException on my web application that I can't fix.  I'm using .NET WebForms, Entity Framework, and Identity Framework.  Here the stack trace of the error which appears when I run the page:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Scheduler.Models.PatientModel.Patient'.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +9898205
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.get_ModelType() +62
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.EvaluateSelectMethodParameters(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, ModelDataSourceMethod method, Boolean isAsyncSelect, DataSourceSelectResultProcessingOptions& selectResultProcessingOptions) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.EvaluateSelectMethodParameters(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceSelectResultProcessingOptions& selectResultProcessingOptions) +17
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.GetSelectMethodResult(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +62
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +15
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +80
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775
```

It happens when I try and load the Patients.aspx page that has this markup in the aspx file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="patientsGridView" runat="server" ItemType="Scheduler.Models.PatientModel.Patient" DataKeyNames="PatientID" 
    SelectMethod="patientsGridView_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="LastName" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="FirstName" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="NickName" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="PhoneNumber" />     
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

That aspx page has the code behind of:

```
public partial class Patients : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<PatientModel.Patient> patientsGridView_GetData()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var query = db.Patients.Where(p => p.Doctor.Id == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return query;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix that exception?

Answer (score 0):

I had erroneously put my patient model within another class, which caused the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think to clarify a bit on this exception if someone else finds it .

What is missing in your code behind example is to show the full namespace of the Patient Object.

So for example. Your Patient Object with full namespace might have been

```
Scheduler.PatientModel.Patient
```

The issue is that on the Grid you are setting the ItemType to an object of type `Scheduler.Models.PatientModel.Patient` and not `Scheduler.PatientModel.Patient`

Point to the right object will fix it . In this example you have to change the markup to

```
 ItemType="Scheduler.PatientModel.Patient"
```

Hope this helps